# append a text to a field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, append, sqlcommand

I have a field named `customerName` in database and might many time this field was Initialized I want save my Previous values and append new value at end of field as string.

**My proc:**

```
CREATE PROC sp_GpInsert
   @CName nvarchar(450),
   @CEmail VARCHAR(250),
   @GName NVARCHAR(70)
AS
BEGIN
   Update TBLGroupCustomers
   SET 
      CustomersName=@CName,
      CustomerEmail=@CEmail
   WHERE GName=@Gname
END
```

**My code:**

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("sp_GpInsert", conn);
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CName", txtCName.Value));
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CEmail", txtemail.Value));
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GName", YrStr));

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This code cannot save the Previous value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do like that

```
Update TBLGroupCustomers
SET 
CustomersName= ISNULL(CustomersName ,'')+ @CName,
CustomerEmail=@CEmail
WHERE GName=@Gname
```

Comment: no it's not working, now name does not added to field

Comment: no error this happen for field have null value because null+string=null but records that have value on CustomersName worked correctly

Comment: thanks it's working, but another question: i want have list in a field of database because i want search in that field a fill some value o field like CustomersName  what i have to do?

Comment: you can search column value using LIKE keyword.please search about it then you can post another Q here.i will delete this comment after few minute because it doesn't belong our thread due to some community rule thanks